# Jaydata - Import from local .s3db file

Tags: sqlite, import, jaydata

We are currently working on a mobile application which will use a jaydata based database. The previous version downloads sqlite database with .s3db extension and inserts it into the database. We have extracted the table information and defined our database in Jaydata with same database schema. All we left to do is to import all rows from the database file. Does Jaydata have any functions to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such function builtin. The best you can do is to import the data into your database with JayData.
One nice way to do that would be to start a server side JayData with nodejs and sqlite, export your data via oData with it and consume the data from client side JayData. You can find examples on JayData site on how to do such synchronization.